# compiler problems with embedded files as char array

Tags: c++, c, char, opencl

I'm trying to embed a file (OpenCL kernel) as char array
the main problem is that it gives me errors for any line containing `#`

example:

```
char mykernel[] =
"stuff ---"
"#if(1)"
"    stuff"
"#else"
"    another stuff"
"#define ASD 15";

void* clh = clsopen(cp,mykernel,CLLD_NOW);
```

all these things are giving me bad errors (compiler errors as if it can't see them)

Edit: semicolon was a mistake in posting question.

Errors are like:

```
#define ASD 15
```

use this ASD in the whole code, get errors like undeclared identifier

use `#if` `#else`

use some function in `#if` and same name in `#else`

get errors like the function is declared 2 times with the same name...and so on

edit2:

```
"#if(1)" //char number 26123: error: note: previous definition is here
"    inline functionA ...with output A"
"#else" //char number 28700: error: redefinition of functionA
"    inline functionA ...with output B"
```

Comment: There's a missing semicolon. It would help if we knew what the error was.

Comment: Maybe you need to add `\n` before `#define`?

Comment: @ qehgt : wow though this is a simple note but it worked :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the lines starting with `#` are also lines that start without any leading whitespace. The problem is that in a natural source file, each line will end with `\n` which the compiler treats as whitespace. Add the `\n` to the end of every line.